# Wildcard letsencrypt не работает на поддомены

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, letsencrypt

Установила этой командой `sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email admin@example.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d site.ru -d *.site.ru`

Прописала txt-запись в dns хостинге `_acme-challenge` с кодом который выдал.
Все вроде правильно, сертификат для `site.ru` работает, сертификат верный, но для `example.site.ru` и для остальных поддоменов не работает и выводит старый просроченный сертификат.
Помогите пожалуйста! Куда копать?

P.S. Конфигурационный файл апача тоже верно настроен и указывает на верную папку `/etc/letsencrypt/live/...`

Comment: « Конфигурационный файл апача тоже верно настроен» — не верю ©

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.ru.conf

Comment: </Directory>
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/cert.pem
       SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

Comment: А после установки/обновления сертификата перезапускали Apache?

Comment: А почему ты при использовании апача пишешь `--manual`, а не `--apache`?

Comment: После обновления конечно была перезагрузка апача, и не раз.

Comment: Насчет --мануала я не совсем понимаю, это все по туториолу делала.

Comment: Ну мануал - это когда ты сама всё умеешь и точно знаешь где и что надо прописать. А указание конкретного типа поддерживаемого вебсервера - сделает тебе в конфигах всё что нужно, чтобы это работало.

Comment: Чё за хауту? Дай ссылку.